# On click run query function script Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, click, dropdown

In my Django project, on my HTML page, I have a script which runs Query depending on the other values ($("#id_report").val() values). Function runs 'on click'. Problem is, when I click on '#id_person' dropdown menu to select an option which I get from query, I run query again and my selection gets reset.

Problem is:

1. I click on dropdown menu
2. Query runs
3. I select one of the options from Query return data
4. When I select, I need to click a selection, Query runs again and my selection is lost I need the script to run only once and dropdown menu is twice a click. First to selet dropdown, second to select an option.

post_form.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">

        <form method="POST" id="PostForm" data-sektor-url="{% url 'ajax_load_sektors' %}" data-department-url="{% url 'ajax_load_departments' %}"  data-person-url="{% url 'ajax_load_persons' %}" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Submit report</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Report</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#id_person").click(function () {
            var value = $("#id_report").val();
            var url = $("#PostForm").attr("data-person-url");
            $.ajax({                      
                url: url,    
                data: {
                'value': value,
                },
                success: function (data) { 
                    $("#id_person").html(data);  
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

How can I run this only when I click on dropdown, not when I select (then it runs again because it's a click).

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, File

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'subject', 'person', 'report']
```

Comment: Are you sure that this question is about python and django?

Comment: is your dropdown from a foreignkey and could you please show your full form ?

Comment: Edited. It's more under 'HTML DOM events JavaScript'. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to help you. Try posting under the HTML, DOM or JQUERY tags

Answer (score 1):

try this  `.change`

```
<script>
    $("#id_person").change(function () {
        var value = $("#id_report").val();
        var url = $("#PostForm").attr("data-person-url");
        $.ajax({                      
            url: url,    
            data: {
            'value': value,
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                $("#id_person").html(data);  
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It does not work. Already tried. Problem is:
1. I click on dropdown menu
2. Query runs
3. I select one of the options from Query return data
4. When I select Query runs again and my selection is lost
I need the script to run only once. And dropdown menu is twice a click. First to selet dropdown, second to select an option.

Comment: what is the problem ? and is this `report` from a foreignkey ?

Comment: @MarkoZg i think i see what you mean could you please show your forms.py for that form.

Comment: @MarkoZg does this dropdown dependent between `report` and `person` ?

Comment: Yes. Depending what is selected in 'Report', a different data will be writen to 'Person'. So when is writen I need to select a Person. It's not an option to write to 'Person' when 'Report' is changed.

Comment: @MarkoZg then why are using this `$("#id_person").change(..)` from what you said above then it should be `$("#id_report").change(..)` am i right ?

Comment: @MarkoZg join this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239398/django-javascript

Comment: Unfortunaly not. I wish to change content of #id_person only when #id_person is clicked on. Change of #id_report doesn't effect anything.